# List.Max(x =>x.ID) Dont work

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-membership, max

I have a table where i have one property called ID_client where is primary key. I have to search the max value from this property and do +1 to assign to a new client. I have the following code..

```
public int IDuser()
    {

        MembershipUserCollection iduser = Membership.GetAllUsers();

        foreach (MembershipUser member in iduser)
        {

            UserEntity entity = new UserEntity();
            entity.Username = member.UserName;
            entity.Roles = "Users";
            entity.Email = member.Email;
            for (int i = 1; i <=iduser.Count; i++)
            {
                entity.ID_client = i;
            }
            _entities.Add(entity);

        }

        int maxID = _entities.Max(x => x.ID_client) +1;

        return maxID;

    }
```

If i create, for example, four users all be ok, 1, 2, 3 and 4. But if i delete third user, i have 1, 2 and 4 as ID_client, and the next new user, i want to assign 5, but this function returns me 4,not 5. Is like the function do a count + 1 instead max value +1.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you deleting the user before it gets assigned to _entities?  Or after?

Comment: What's the purpose of that for loop?

Comment: I delete him before to create the new user.

Comment: Can't you use an autoincrement column instead?

Comment: Aren't you renumbering all the ids in your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name you gave to your method does not reflect what the method is supposed to do. Give it a speaking name. I do not see what the inner loop is supposed to do. Drop it. Get the maximum id BEFORE adding new records. Maybe you want something like this

```
public int CopyMembershipUsersToUserEntities()
{
    int lastID = _entities.Max(x => x.ID_client); 
    foreach (MembershipUser member in Membership.GetAllUsers()) 
    { 
        UserEntity entity = new UserEntity(); 
        entity.Username = member.UserName; 
        entity.Roles = "Users"; 
        entity.Email = member.Email; 
        entity.ID_client = ++lastID; 
        _entities.Add(entity); 
    } 
    return lastID; 
}
```

As others have already said, you could also use an auto increment column. This is safer in a multiuser environment.

Comment: Ok thanks Olivier. This code dont work because when try to read entities.Max still isnt exists and show an exception. How is the best way to compare if list is null or empty?

Comment: If ((_entities != null && _entities.Any()) { ... }

Answer (score 3):

Your code resets ID_client on all of the entities. So if you delete one user the ones left will have ID_client set to 1,2,3 or 4. Therefore List.Max() is correctly returning 4

Comment: Ok, the method that i used is to search in a list, but is there a method to search the max value on an object property? Or if i can use any autoincrement method if i dont use a physical database, with azure.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Enable auto-incrementation of field "ID" on database level - all that code will be redundant.

Comment: I use windows azure storage, i cant define on database level.

Answer (score 0):

Is very strange, but i have solved my mistake as here..

Before store the membershipUser, i store it in a list..

```
            uentity.Username = username;
            for(int i=1;i<1000;i++) 
            {
                uentity.ID_client = i;
            }
            _entities.Add(uentity);
```

And then create a membershipUser..

```
      userDataSource.Insert(new UserEntity(
      GetPartitionKeyFromUsername(username).ToString(),
      String.Empty)
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = EncodePassword(password),
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                IsDeleted = DefaultValues.IsDeleted,
                IsLockedOut = DefaultValues.IsLockedOut,
                IsApproved = DefaultValues.IsApproved,
                ApplicationName = applicationName,
                Email = email,
                PasswordQuestion = passwordQuestion,
                PasswordAnswer = passwordAnswer,
                Gender = DefaultValues.Gender,
                LastProfileUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastPasswordChangedDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastLoginDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1),
                LastLockedOutDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1),
                FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1),
                FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1),
                Birthday = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1),
                Roles = Roles(username),
                ID_client = IDuser(username)
            });
```

And the method to give me always one autoincrement ID because if i delete a membershipuser i dont delete from the list..

```
    public int IDuser(string username)
    {

        int lastID;

        if (username=="Admin")
        {
            lastID=1;

        }

        else
        {

            lastID = _entities.Count();
        }

        return lastID;
    }
```

But i have an answer,i use

```
  lastID = _entities.Count();
```

instead of

```
  lastID = _entities.Max(x => x.ID_client)
```

Because the _entities.Max for the second user gives me 999, not the number 2. It is as gives me the remaining capacity, not the max value of ID_client(2).

Someone can tell me why happen this?

Thanks.